# NullPointerException when parsing URL to ImageIcon

Tags: java, file-io, nullpointerexception

I am following few tutorials on JMonkey2.1

When I run those tutorials I get NullPointerExceptions where new ImageIcons are loaded using java.net.URL.

```
// generate a terrain texture with 3 textures
ProceduralTextureGenerator pt = new ProceduralTextureGenerator(heightMap);
pt.addTexture(new ImageIcon(Lesson3.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path/to/file")), -128, 0, 128); //line 199
pt.addTexture(new ImageIcon(Lesson3.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dirt.jpg")), 0, 128, 255);
pt.addTexture(new ImageIcon(Lesson3.class.getClassLoader().getResource("highest.jpg")), 128, 255, 384);
pt.createTexture(32);
```

But when I parse file path as a string instead of reading them as java.net.URL they work fine.

e.g:   `new ImageIcon("path/to/file")`

This is the stack trace

```
Jun 4, 2011 4:18:22 PM class jme.test.Lesson3 start()
SEVERE: Exception in game loop
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:167)
at jme.test.Lesson3.buildTerrain(Lesson3.java:199)
at jme.test.Lesson3.initGame(Lesson3.java:151)
at com.jme.app.BaseGame.start(BaseGame.java:74)
at jme.test.Lesson3.main(Lesson3.java:62)
at jme.test.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Jun 4, 2011 4:18:22 PM com.jme.app.BaseGame start
INFO: Application ending.
```

What might be the reason for this?
Thank you..

Comment: The images are not located where you're looking.  The path passed into the getResource must be relative to the class file locations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use `ClassLoader#getResource()`, the resource needs to be in the classpath.

When it's located in the **same** package as `Lesson3` class, then do so

```
new ImageIcon(Lesson3.class.getResource("image.png"));
```

When it's located in a **different** package, then use an absolute path from the classpath root on, i.e. start with `/`.

```
new ImageIcon(Lesson3.class.getResource("/com/example/image.png"));
```

This expects the file `image.png` to be in the package `com.example`.

Using `new File()` is not recommended for relative paths as it depends on the current working directory which in turn depends on the way how you started the application which is not controllable from inside the application.

Comment: I copied images in to the package directory where Lesson3.java resides, but it didn't solve the problem. Do I have to set class path separately? I am using Netbeans.

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, but does it take non `.java` files in the build? It should do.

Comment: yes. all the files in the directory is included in the output package.

Comment: And the `getResource()` still returns `null`? E.g. `System.out.println(Lesson.class.getResource("image.png"));` now prints `null`? Or is the `NullPointerException` now caused by something else?

Comment: ah problem solved :) it should be `Lesson3.class.getResource("mypkg/image.png")` assuming `Lesson3.java` belongs to `mypkg`. Thank you very much for all the help

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. Don't you have another `Lesson3` class in a different package?

Comment: nope this is the only project I am working on and this is the only project loaded to Netbeans. I Dont think there is any Lesson3 class shipped with JMonkey.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get path files relative to your class and getclass().get recourse does not work, use a File. Make a fie with the name with the image and use new imageIcon(file.getAbsoltuePath);

I cant really show you an example because I'm on my iPad.